# Sigue manteniendo el estado al eliminar una card user - React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hola estoy a punto de terminar la sgte [aplicacion](https://husdady.github.io/created-from-friendships/) y me he tomado con algo inesperado. Explicacion del problema: al entrar a la app, se muestran 3 usuarios, al cambiar la imagen de cualquiera de estos, aparece una camara que es un input file que sirve para actualizar la imagen, aparece tanto en la imagen de usuario y en el fondo de usuario.

Entonces cuando se carga una nueva imagen, esta se reemplaza con la actual, al eliminar esa card user teniendo consigo una camara en la imagen de usuario o fondo o si se ha modificado la imagen con una nueva imagen de usuario o fondo, tanto la camara o la nueva imagen pasan a la card user que esta despues de la card user eliminada.

Ejm más claro por si no se entendio lo de arriba: Al usuario Aristide se cambia su imagen por una nueva, entonces decido eliminar a Aristide, ahora cuando es eliminado, Lara María hereda la imagen nueva de Aristide y aparece de igual manera la camara. ¿Por que sucede esto? . A continuacion el codigo donde renderizo la card user:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Icon from '../assets/Icon';
import LoadImage from '../assets/LoadImage';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

const ListFriendships = props => {
  const {
    fondoImagen,
    imagenUsuario,
  } = props,

    /* Mostrar camara */
    [showCamera, setShowCamera] = useState(false),

    /* Cambiar icono de editar y check */
    [edit, setEdit] = useState(false),

    /* Capturando la actual img de usuario */
    [actualUserImg, setActualUserImg] = useState(''),

    /* Capturando la actual img de fondo */
    [actualBackgroundImg, setActualBackgroundImg] = useState(''),

    loadImage = e => {
      const { name } = e.target,
        file = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0], reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
        if (name === 'userImg') {
          setActualUserImg(reader.result);
        } else {
          setActualBackgroundImg(reader.result);
        }
      }, false)
      file && reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    };

  return (
    <div className="person">

      <article className="image-person">

        <img className="background-image" src={!actualBackgroundImg ? `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${fondoImagen}` : actualBackgroundImg} alt="background" />

        {showCamera
          ? <LoadImage
            onChange={e => {
              loadImage(e);
            }}
            name="backgroundImg"
            id="file"
          />
          : null}

      </article>

      <article className="name-person">
        {!edit
          ? <Icon title="Editar" className="fas fa-edit"
            onClick={() => {
              setShowCamera(true);
              setEdit(true);
            }} />
          : <Icon title="Aplicar cambios" className="fas fa-check" onClick={() => {
            confirmLoadImage();
          }} />
        }
        <Icon title="Eliminar" className="fas fa-trash" onClick={() => {
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'warning',
            iconColor: '#BBB45B',
            html: `<h3 id="messageForDeleteFriend">¿Estás seguro(a) que deseas eliminar a ${nombreDeUsuario}?</h3>`,
            background: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.85)',
            showDenyButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: `Eliminar`,
            denyButtonText: `Descartar`,
            confirmButtonColor: '#A80000',
            denyButtonColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.15)',
          }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
              props.deleteFriendship();
              props.showFriendsDelete();
            } else if (result.isDenied) {
              return null;
            }
          })
        }} />
        <figure>
          <img src={!actualUserImg ? `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/${imagenUsuario}` : actualUserImg} alt={nombreDeUsuario} title={nombreDeUsuario} onClick={() => showModal()} />

          {showCamera
            ? <LoadImage
              onChange={e => {
                loadImage(e);
              }}
              name="userImg"
              id="file1"
            />
            : null}

        </figure>
      </article>
    </div>
  )
};

export default ListFriendships;
```

Estoy usando `SweetAlert` para generar los mensajes de confirmacion para eliminar un card user, la verdad no entiendo porque sigue manteniendo el estado de `[showCamera, actualUserImg, actualBackgroundImg]` en la anterior tarjeta de la tarjeta que es eliminada. El componente `<LoadImage />` solo me genera la camara:

```js
const LoadImage = props => {
  const {onChange, id, name} = props;
  return (
    <div className="edit-image">
      <input onChange={onChange} name={name} type="file" id={id} accept="image/*" />
      <label htmlFor={id} className="load-image"></label>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoadImage;
```

Ahora el componente que renderiza cada card user, lo renderizo en el sgte componente:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './css/styles.css';

/* Components */
import ListFriendships from './ListFriendships';

/* JSON */
import friendships from '../json/friendships';

const Friendship = () => {

  const [person, setPerson] = useState(friendships);

  const deleteCardPerson = (x, index) => {
    const newState = x.filter((e, i) => {
      return i !== index;
    });
    setPerson(newState);
  }

  return (

    <div id="container">

      <section id="friendships">
        <h3>Tu lista de amistades :</h3>
        <div id="content-person">
          {person.map((x, index) => (
              <ListFriendships
                key={index}
                fondoImagen={x.fondoImagen}
                imagenUsuario={x.imagenUsuario}
        
                index={index}

                deleteFriendship={() => deleteCardPerson(person, index)}
                showFriendsDelete={() => showFriendsDelete(x)}
              />
            ))
          }
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Friendship;
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda. Es lo ultimo que me falta solucionar para terminar la app y empezar a aprender nuevas cosas. A continuacion dejo los componentes en el sgte [github](https://github.com/Husdady/created-from-friendships/tree/master).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te pasa eso, debido a la `key` que le asocias a cada `ListFriendships`:

```
<ListFriendships
    key={index}
    ...
```

El index del array no es un elemento único de cada objeto del array, es la posición del elemento en el array, entonces al quitar un elemento del array, cuando vuelve a renderizar, no vincula correctamente cada index con sus props.

Quizá alguien sabe dar una explicación mas técnica.

Puedes solucionar esto, asigandole un id único a cada persona, por ejemplo 1,2 y 3 en el json:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "fondoImagen": "img/background-image.jpg",
    "imagenUsuario": "img/users/user-1.jpg",
    ...
```

Y utilizando este id en vez del index como key:

```
<ListFriendships
    key={x.id}
    ...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Tassio, la verdad nunca pense que el problema era por la key, pero haciendo unos test pude comprobar que lo que dices es correcto !!